Wix 4 Trouble Setting LogPathVariable for a Bundle
I created a bundle to install my app's msi along with .NET 8 runtime. That seems to work fine, but one thing I need is to have the MSI log to be stored in my application's directory. Here's what I do.
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

<Variable Name="LOGPATH_PROP" Type="string" Value="[CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86]\MyCompany\MyApp\logs" />
  
<Chain>
    <!-- Check if .NET 8 is installed -->
    <ExePackage
        Id="Net8Runtime"
        SourceFile="dotnet-runtime-8.0.10-win-x64.exe"
        InstallArguments="/install /quiet /norestart"
        Permanent="yes"
        Compressed="yes"
        Vital="yes" />
    
    <MsiPackage 
        SourceFile="..\MyBuildPath\myapp-installer.msi"
        LogPathVariable="LOGPATH_PROP" />
</Chain>

</Bundle>
</Wix>

This is mainly needed when our update service downloads and runs the bundle to upgrade the product. So, in this case, the app directory and its logs directory already exist.
I've tried setting the variable's Value to a hard-coded path with no spaces and no permission issues. Yet, it still doesn't put the log there. According to the docs, it should be easy. And I think I followed what others have said to do. What can I try next?
